# Magento Mixpanel PHP Library

Tags: php, magento, javascript, mixpanel

How do I add new PHP lib from Mixpanel Analytics to Magento.

Here is the actual link to the library:
https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/php

Inside the github file I've downloaded there is a folder called lib, which I have renamed to Mixpanel and placed it within /lib folder in Magento - but will Magento autoload this or do I need to add a line of code such as:

```
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/Mixpanel/MixpanelBase.php');
```

Part II

Now I need to import the data from the database for every event I have. See the DEMO: http://mpdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/import-old-signup-events-demo.php

In my file I have got the following:

```
class Mixpanel_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
public $token;
public $api_key;
public $host = 'http://api.mixpanel.com/';

public function __construct($token_string,$api_key) {
    $this->token = Mage::getStoreConfig('mixpanel_options/settings/mixpanel_token');
    $this->api_key = Mage::getStoreConfig('mixpanel_options/settings/mixpanel_api_key');
}

public function track($event, $properties = array()) {

    $params = array(
        'event' => $event,
        'properties' => $properties
        );
    if (!isset($params['properties']['token'])){
        $params['properties']['token'] = $this->token;
    }
    $url = $this->host . 'import/?data=' . base64_encode(json_encode($params)) . "&api_key=$this->api_key";
    exec("curl '" . $url . "' >/dev/null 2>&1 &"); 
}
}
```

Now I am not sure how to use this code to make it work with what I already have, and can this code run for all events or will I need to create this for all individual functions (instead of birthday I want to get data for login):

```
$metrics = new EventImporter("TOKEN_HERE","API_KEY_HERE");

foreach($users as $id=>$birthdate){
 $props = array();
 $props['distinct_id'] = $id; //distinct_id should be your identifier
 $props['time'] = strtotime($birthdate); //time should be their $birthdate
 $event = '$signup'; //you are sending the $signup event. You could also put $born here. 
 echo "\nSending $event event for ".$props['distinct_id']." at $birthdate (".$props['time'].")\n";

 $metrics->track($event, $props);
}
```

This is the function I have for tracking login:

```
public function trackCustomerLogin($observer) {

    $this->track('customer_action', array('action'          => 'login',
                                          'distinct_id'     => $this->getCustomerIdentity()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Magento autoloader will replace the underscores with slashes and add a `.php` to the end. i.e.:

- `new Some_Class_Name` -> `require_once 'lib/Some/Class/Name.php'`

If you extract the files directly into the lib folder you should be able to autoload Mixpanel classes, e.g. these files should be at

- `/magento/lib/MixpanelBase.php`
- `/magento/lib/Base/MixpanelBase.php`

etc.  Then you will be able to use `$var = new MixpanelBase();` in Magento without using include statements.

Comment: Great! Now am stuck with importing the old data from my database, please review once again the additional information provided, hopefully there is very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have renamed the lib folder to Mixpanel, then you should add that to the classes names as prefix:
Example: 

`class Base_MixpanelBase`

will become:

`class Mixpanel_Base_MixpanelBase`

Then remove all of the require_once() calls by commenting them and don't forget to change all of the class names by adding the prefix: Mixpanel_ to their names, but don't change the file names.
This way you will follow the way Varien and Zend libraries are written and you can call the classes directly like this:

`$mixPanelBase = new Mixpanel_Base_MixpanelBase($options);`

without the require_once calls. Magento will take care of the autoloading.